# Spark web framework logging requests and responses

Tags: java, logging, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm using the [Spark web framework](http://sparkjava.com/) to develop a REST API. Is there a way to automatically log all incoming requests and outgoing responses (query params, headers, status codes, etc) or do I need to manually add logging for each one of the handlers?

The Spark documentation has nothing on this subject.

Thanks.

Comment: I would also like to know the "best practices" way to do this with Spark. A quick Ctrl+F "logging" on the Spark documentation page turns up nothing.

Answer (score 12):

Here's was my workaround.

```
private static String requestInfoToString(Request request) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(request.requestMethod());
    sb.append(" " + request.url());
    sb.append(" " + request.body());
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Bunch of handlers

    before((request, response) -> {
        log.info(requestInfoToString(request));
    });
}
```

Comment: A useful snippet. However, do you know of a way to log responses? I tried playing around with responses, no luck, can't get the body back.

Comment: @pfh: you could use the after(...) filter to log the responses.

Comment: @RanilWijeyratne: Thanks, there was an issue with the Spark version 2.3. Upgrading to latest seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon Joe's answer... here's a version that'll do both request and reponse:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ... all your other handlers

    // add logger
    after((request, response) -> {
        LOG.info(requestAndResponseInfoToString(request, response));
    });
}

private static String requestAndResponseInfoToString(Request request, Response response) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(request.requestMethod());
    sb.append(" " + request.url());
    sb.append(" " + request.body());
    HttpServletResponse raw = response.raw();
    sb.append(" Reponse: " + raw.getStatus());
    sb.append(" " + raw.getHeader("content-type"));
    try {
        sb.append(" body size in bytes: " + response.body().getBytes(raw.getCharacterEncoding()).length);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: `sb.append(" Reponse: " + raw.getStatus());` ... I tried to change " Reponse: " to "Response: " but apparently edits have to be at least 6 characters. Either way thanks for the useful code!

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // add logger
    after((request, response) -> {
        LOG.info(String.format("%s %s", request.requestMethod(), request.url()));
    });
}
```